# Using msbuild to package a website using Content Items from csproj file

Tags: msbuild, csproj

I've written an msbuild script to package a webapp as follows:

```
<Project
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
    ToolsVersion="4.0"
    DefaultTargets="Main">

    <PropertyGroup>         
        <WebAppSourceDir>e:\Web</WebAppSourceDir>
    </PropertyGroup>        

    <Import Project="$(WebAppSourceDir)\WebApp.csproj"/>

    <ItemGroup>
        <BuiltFiles Include="$(WebAppSourceDir)\bin\**\*.*"/>
    </ItemGroup>            

    <Target Name="Main" DependsOnTargets="" >
        <Copy SourceFiles="$(WebAppSourceDir)\%(Content.Identity)"
            DestinationFiles="c:\temp\buildoutput\%(Content.Identity)" Condition="%(Content.Link) == ''"/>

        <Copy SourceFiles="@(BuiltFiles)"
            DestinationFolder="c:\temp\buildoutput\bin\%(RecursiveDir)"/>
    </Target>       
</Project>
```

This works fine, but we build multiple web projects in our solution and they are all packaged at the same time with the same greater msbuild project.  So how can I specifically ask for just the Content Items of a given csproj file at any one time?

Alternatively... what is a better way of doing what I'm trying to achieve?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Web Deployment Projects?  You can then call the Packaging target.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/04/14/visual-studio-2010-web-deployment-projects-beta-avail-now.aspx

Comment: Yes that's what we're currently using but I don't like it the package and copy is the only part of it that we're relying on so I am trying to recreate that myself.

Comment: @Gaz - Why don't you just import those MSBuild tasks into your own targets file and leverage them however you like then?

Comment: @Gaz - let me know how it goes... I use the Web.config transform task in a generalized way to apply it to App.config and silverlight WCF clientConfig files and it works like a charm.

Comment: I can't stand that config transform. Too much friction to add a new item for my likings.. I wrote my own!